# is .equal() method checks null condition internally in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to know if **.equals()** method checks null condition internally in JAVA or we have to do this a.equals(null).

Answer (score 1):

`.equals()` does not check null condition and neither does `a.equals(null)` because the arguement must be an object, which `null` is not.

What you should use is `a!=null && a.equals(b)`

If `a` is `null` the statement will short-circuit, never calling `.equals` and preventing a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Every class which is a **direct** subclass of the `Object` class does inherit the implementation of the `equals()` method of the `Object` class. And this implementation **does not** have any null check. The only thing it checks is whether the two objects being compared are the same instance.

If you want to use it, you should override it yourself.